# "He grew up around cars that would later become classics."

Tags: meaning, past-tense, modal-verbs

My question is about the use of *would* in the following sentence.

> He grew up around cars that **would** later become classics.

The use of *would* in this particular sense always looks confusing to me because it's so different from:

I *would* like to know...
I don't think he *would* agree to that...
*Would* you mind....
*Would* it be alright if I...
etc.

The above sentence, as I see it, means "he grew up around cars which *were going to* become classics in the future". Is that correct? If yes, does it also mean that the cars *actually became* classics later?

Comment: Could just as easily be _He grew up around cars that later **became** classics_. He didn't know it at the time. It's a style preference.

Comment: or even *...cars later **to become** classics*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes and yes—this is an example of what is called [the sequence of tenses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_of_tenses#English), which relates the tense of a subordinate clause to that of the head clause. It's the same reason why one would usually write *he grew up with cars that were painted blue* instead of *he grew up with cars that are painted blue*. In particular, the use of *would* here is a relic of its origin as the praeterite of *will*; similarly, one would use in such a case *should* for *shall*, *could* for *can*, and *might* for *may*.

Comment: +1 Although, the OP might have just meant to ask the lexical meaning of *would*, if it indeed meant 'were going to'.

Answer (score 5):

> The above sentence, as I see it, means he grew up around cars which were going to become classics in the future. Is that correct?

Yes.

> If yes, does it also mean that the cars actually became classics later?

Yes; *would* here is concrete and definite.

Comment: There is a subtle complication. _He grew up among people who would later become famous_ implies that the people he lived with would actually become famous. _He grew up around cars that would later become classics_ means that the _models_ he was familiar with were to become classics.

Answer (score 1):

See the Thesaurus entry from the Macmillan Dictionary:

> **[would](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus/british/would#would_9)** modal verb
>   **1 b** used for talking about something that was going to happen after a particular point in the past

[e.g.](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/would) *Here she met the man who would one day become her husband.*

The latter page also lists a number of meanings and usage variants of *would*. It records towards the end, almost as a second thought, that *would* is ", incidentally, " used as the past tense of *will*!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Macmillan Dictionary & Thesaurus. It's another useful reference resource I came to know about.